# How could a commit on remote survive a forced push?

Tags: git

I leak a credentials on a file in my feature branch. A reviewer caught the mistake, showing the hash commit, lets call it `a6859b6`, when the bad info was introduced and asked me to safely remove. I edited the file, squashed all commits in my branch and forced push.

Then the PR got approved, and merged into master. My branch is deleted on remote and locally. The commit log of master doesn't show any presence of the "bad" commit `a6859b6`

Surprisingly, querying remote on the exact commit hash https://gitlab.com/blabla/-/commit/a6859b6 still show the offending code.

Is it by design? How do we call this kind of "orphan" commits? What does git do with these and is it possible to purge a specific orphan commit?

EDIT: GitLab answered to my support ticket

- Advise to rotate the leak creds.
- GitLab has a [housekeeping](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/housekeeping.html)  process which prunes the loose commits on the remote repo automatically every 2 weeks

Comment: Git doesn't delete unreferenced commits (as well as other objects) immediately, that is done by occasional [garbage collections](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc). You don't usually need to do those explicitly, they will be done occasionally. But one *can* trigger them explicitly for local repositories. How any given *remote* repository handles this is up to them. [Gitlab has this page, for example](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/housekeeping.html).

Comment: FYI the commit is not orphan, it has a parent. The commit is not reachable through a branch "pointer" though.

Comment: I would try asking gitlab support if they can remove the commit.

Comment: @GaëlJ the parent commits (and recursively parents of parents, etc.) end up to the point where my branch was branched off `master`. Along that chain of parents many also disappeared from the current commit logs (ie. their hash doesn't appear in git log on master nor any branch). In our team we delete the remote branch after merge.

Comment: @JBallin I have already file a Premium support ticket with GitLab. Not yet get any answer. Surprisingly I got much faster feedback on SO.  @Joachim comment above shows the Gitlab Housekeeping page. I don't have access to the admin settings to see the interval between `git gc` but it has been 4 days already. However I can trigger `Run Housekeeping` on the repo settings. Let's see what GitLab answers and I will update the post accordingly.

Comment: If you pushed the credential, you have to assume it's now exposed to anyone who can see that repository now or in the future, so you should rotate it immediately, regardless of whether you delete the data from the history.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it by design?

Yes, git does not instantly delete objects once they are not referenced. This may be done eventually by the GC (`git gc`). Not instantly removing such references makes it easy for you to recover lost data using `git reflog` (as long as you have added/committed the data previously).

> How do we call this kind of "orphan" commits?

You can call them loose objects/commit. This name is [also used in the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc#Documentation/git-gc.txt---pruneltdategt).

> What does git do with these and is it possible to purge a specific orphan commit?

Git may eventually decide to clean these up (depending on [`gc.auto`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-gcauto)). This can also be done manually by running `git gc --prune=now` in the repository where you want to remove it (you need shell access). If you have a long reference chain referencing the object that is not referenced any more, you may want to add `--aggressive`: `git gc --aggressive --prune=now`.

If you don't have direct access, you could mirror the repository, run `git gc --prune=now`, delete the remote repository, recreate an empty repository and push everything from your local mirror.

Anyways, I would **strongly recommend you to change/invalidate the leaked credentials as soon as possible** as people could already have downloaded your commit (and the reviewer has seen those, too). When you are sure that your leaked credentials are not valid anywhere, you don't need to worry about unreferenced commits.

Comment: The remote repos is on GitLab, the Web GUI has a "Settings, General, Advanced" which has a button "Housekeeping" which says "Runs a number of housekeeping tasks within the current repository, such as compressing file revisions and removing unreachable objects." I suppose this runs the `git gc` as you explained. Not sure how often GitLab does the GC because that commit was dereferenced 4 days ago.

Comment: You might be able to manually trigger that or modify it to remove those earlier or wait but you may want to make sure that there are no references (also not in merge request histories etc, I don't know whether GitLab removes them, too).